# Function that takes a string and returns word count

Tags: javascript, string, foreach, destructuring

> Create a function that takes a string and returns the word count. The string will be a sentence.

***Sample Output:***

`countWords("This is a test") ➞ 4`

**CODE**

```js
function countWords(str) {

    let count = 0;
   
    [...str].forEach(x => x.length > 0)
      
    count++

    return count

}

countWords("Hello World")
```

When I call this function, I get `undefined is not iterable`. Am I using the spread operator wrong?

Also, is there a way to get the count in a less verbose way, within the forEach or otherwise? I believe the increment needs to be inside the forEach but am not sure where to put it.

Comment: You could do it with .split()      :         
ex : return str.split(' ').length;

Comment: Syntactically all is okay with how you use spread syntax. The problem is with the rest: 1) What's `0` second argument for the `forEach`? 2) What does `x => x.length > 0` function passed as a first argument to `Array.prototype.forEach` do? 3) Your `count++` is unconditional

Comment: ok got rid of the `0`, thought i needed a value to start on or something. The 2nd part, thought that was addressed with the spread operator, putting each word into it's own string.

Comment: "spread operator, putting each word into it's own string" --- spread syntax knows nothing about "words" (what does a "word" even mean), it splits the string to characters (not always visible, unicode is complicated).

Comment: ok got it, so to be able to use the operator with the str to get the count would be?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *split* the string with space character to create an array and return the *length* of that array:

```js
function countWords(str) {
  let count = str.split(' ').length;
  return count;
}

console.log(countWords("This is a test"));
```

Comment: Not to say I never do the same, but this answer would teach OP nothing: they have a solution indeed, they have no idea how to solve something a bit different themselves though.

Comment: No reason for that `let`, though. Just `return str.split(' ').length;`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this code

```js
function countWords(){
 s = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
 s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
 s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
 s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
 document.getElementById("wordcount").value = s.split(' ').length;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inputString" cols="50" rows="4">Text to count</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" name="Convert" value="Count Words" onClick="countWords()"> 
<input id="wordcount" type="text" value="" size="6">
```

Comment: appreciate the response, but i was looking for a solution to the spread operator issue